# Picante's pblm error: "Error in V1[rownames (assocs), rownames(assocs)]: subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, dendrogram, bipartite, phylogeny

I am trying to calculate signal strength using the `pblm` function from [picante](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/picante/picante.pdf) (for phylocom integration) in R. It seems like I don't understand how the input should be constructed. I built a simple example to test out the program with 2 simple phylogenetic trees (dendrograms) and a matrix for their association strength:

```
require(ape)
require(picante)

tree1<-read.tree(text="((C,B),A);")
tree2<-read.tree(text="((G,F),(E,D));")

web = matrix(
c(0, 5, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1),
nrow=4,
ncol=3,
byrow = TRUE,
dimnames = list(c("D","E","F","G"),c("A","B","C")))

pblm(web,tree1=tree1,tree2=tree2)
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Error in V1[rownames(assocs), rownames(assocs)] : subscript out of bounds
```

What is wrong with my input in `pblm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the function calls a row that is not present in the provided data. Here, the problem was that the matrix was transposed.

```
pblm(t(web), tree1=tree1, tree2=tree2)
```

Comment: Great! That was the solution. However, with my actual dataset I transposed the dataset to no longer receive the error above ( `Error in V1...` ), but instead received this similar error:

`Error in V2[colnames(assocs), colnames(assocs)] : subscript out of bounds`

I was unable to reproduce this error with my simple example above so didn't post it as a new question

Comment: Try transposing. Alternatively, there might be a typo in species names in the tree with respect to the table - especially, if there is whitespace in names.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the V2 error comes from when there are entries in the matrix that aren't present in the tree (though the program still runs if there are entries in the tree that aren't in the matrix).

Comment: Also as a note for others, in my real example I had to `gsub` in underscores into my matrix to match the underscores from the Newick tree input.